# 'Unicode' is an invalid connection string attribute Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, unicode, connection-string

My code have error ---- 'Unicode' is an invalid connection string attribute

Web Config :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****;Unicode=True"
  providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

Asp.net:

```
 public DataTable Bankomat(DataTable dt)
    {

        using (con = new OracleConnection())
        {
            using (cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from bankomat";
                con.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Your code have not error. Your config have error. Also, it looks like you're trying to revive an ancient version of ASP.NET, so please have a look at http://www.asp.net/get-started for how you can do ASP.NET these days.

Comment: remove this `Unicode=True`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****;Unicode=True"
```

the `Unicode=True`  is belong to [System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OracleClient_OracleConnection_ConnectionString) and not to **Oracle.DataAccess.Client**

So just remove it.